# App Bundle configurar módulos apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

La pregunta es referente a los App Bundle. Es decir, en lugar de generar un *apk* final, creamos un archivo *aab* que será subido a la Play Store. Y la PS automáticamente genera diferentes *apk* para adaptarse a cada dispositivo. Entonces, cada dispositivo descarga solo los recursos necesarios para él. Por ejemplo, si tienes una tablet con mucha resolución, cuando descargas la app, automáticamente se selecciona la apk más adecuada a tu dispositivo. Esto es las imágenes grandes, la configuración de tu pantalla, etc. Osea, en lugar de descargar un apk de, por ejemplo, 20 megas con todas las configuraciones, descarga un apk de 12 megas.

En este enlace se explica https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery#modularize

Igual pasa con los idiomas. Si tu app tiene varios idiomas en diferentes strings, la descarga desde la PS será solo del idioma de tu dispositivo, y cuando tu dispositivo cambie de idioma, automáticamente se descargará ese otro idioma.

El caso es que para que mi app funcione correctamente necesita tener todos los strings de todos los idiomas. Porque desde la app se puede cambiar el idioma manualmente. Pero al generar el App Bundle, el usuario solo se descarga el idioma de su dispositivo y eso hace que no cambie el idioma cuando lo haces manualmente desde la app.

¿Cómo puedo configurar que siempre se carguen todos los idiomas (strings)?

Lo siguiente me aparece en el analisis de Android Vitals. Es la optimización de este App Bundle. Lo que yo quiero realmente es que no se implemente el último punto:

> **Optimizaciones del tamaño de la aplicación**
>
> **Habilita la ofuscación y la reducción de código** *No implementado*
>
> **Habilita los APK de configuración para distintas ABI**
>   *Implementado*
>
> Añade compatibilidad con parte de configuración ABI en tu Android App
>   Bundle y Dynamic Delivery de Google Play generará APK optimizados para
>   cada ABI. De esta forma, el tamaño de descarga de la aplicación se
>   reducirá para los usuarios, ya que se retirarán las bibliotecas de las
>   ABI que su dispositivo no cargue. Más información
>
> **Habilita los APK de configuración para distintas densidades de pantalla**
>   *Implementado*
>
> Añade compatibilidad con distintas densidades de pantalla en tu
>   Android App Bundle para que Dynamic Delivery de Google Play genere APK
>   optimizados para cada densidad de pantalla. De esta forma, el tamaño
>   de descarga de la aplicación se reducirá para los usuarios, ya que
>   solo recibirán los recursos necesarios para su dispositivo. Más
>   información
>
> **Habilita los APK de configuración para distintos idiomas**
>   *Implementado*
>
> Añade compatibilidad con distintas configuraciones de idioma en tu
>   Android App Bundle para que Dynamic Delivery de Google Play genere APK
>   optimizados para cada idioma que incluyas. De esta forma, el tamaño de
>   descarga de la aplicación se reducirá para los usuarios, ya que solo
>   recibirán los idiomas que coincidan con sus preferencias. Para
>   descargar más idiomas según sea necesario, usa la API de idiomas
>   adicionales. Más información

Espero que se me haya entendido.
1000 gracias

Comment: Como sabes que solo descarga el idioma de su dispositivo? , si agregas los strings.xml para cada idioma, estos son siempre instalados. Lo que deseas configurar es lo que en realidad ya tienes y no necesitas configuración. Añade detalles a tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, he editado mi pregunta. Espero que se entienda mejor. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He obtenido la respuesta desde otra pregunta hecha en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054175/handle-dynamic-language-change-within-the-app-on-android-app-bundle

La solución fue agregar lo siguiente al build.gradle(Module:app)

```
android {

    ...
    bundle {
        language {
            // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
            // configuration APKs for language resources. These
            // resources are instead packaged with each base and
            // dynamic feature APK.
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

Con esto siempre se guardarán todos los idiomas en todos los archivos apk resultantes.